# gcloud:run error Application does not exist

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-3, maven-plugin, gcloud

When I run mvn clean compile, I get the files under "target" folder in my project.After this when I run mvn gcloud:run and I get this error.

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.10
6.v20160420:run (default-cli) on project HelloSpringWorld: The application direc
tory does not exist : D:\Maven_project\HelloSpringWorld\target/HelloSpringWorld-
0.1.0 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I don't have any "HelloSpringWorld-0.1.0" folder inside my target folder.I don't know why it is pointing to it.How can I change gcloud:run to point to "target" folder instead of "target/HelloSpringWorld-0.1.0" please ?

my pom.xml , for the gcloud plugin

<

```
build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9.106.v20160420</version>
                <configuration>
                    <gcloud_directory>C:\Users\RPalliyalil\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk</gcloud_directory>
                    <verbosity>debug</verbosity>
                    <staging_directory>D:\Maven_project\HelloSpringWorld\target</staging_directory>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: please post your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

Did you follow the guide? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin

According to the guide, you should be running `mvn clean install` before actually running `mvn gcloud:run`. Also verify you have a WAR project, that is project with `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

If you do this correctly, during `package` phase maven-war-plugin will generate folder `/target/${project.build.finalName}`. In your case it means 
`/target/HelloSpringWorld-0.1.0`.